# Laser output below, just above and way above threshold?

Tags: atomic-physics, laser

I've been reading up on lasers recently and learnt that within the cavity while the laser light is amplified by the gain coefficient, it loses power due to transmission and absorption.

Suppose the pumping radiation comes from a monochromatic source whose energy is not exactly equal to the energy difference between the two levels.

For laser operation below threshold, due to broadening of the levels there would be overlap between pumping radiation and energy gap it would still be possible to stimulate gain?

But if it the gain way above threshold, there is no overlap between the pumping radiation and energy difference between the two levels as the peaks become very sharp. Would the gain be 0 then?

[image]

Comment: A laser is, at least, a three level system. What you are pumping is the third and highest level, which can and ideally should have a broad absorption band that has nothing to do with the actual lasing levels. If your pump source falls short of that energy, of course, then nothing much will happen. I think you are mistaking the pumping with the actual amplification between the second level and the ground level and how the bandwidth gets modified by the resonator. Other than that I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: I'm trying to sketch the power spectrum of a ND:YAG laser, being pumped at - below threshold, just above threshold and way above threshold

Comment: Way above threshold the laser becomes chaotic, more than slightly above threshold you start exciting multiple modes, leading to a rather complicated theory of laser dynamics... and in all cases you have to look at it as a multilevel system. Nd:YAG is a poor choice for a sketch, anyway. Did you look at it's actual level diagram? http://www.rp-photonics.com/img/ndyag_levels.png What you are exciting are the two blue transitions and the laser resonator is tuned to one the red transitions.

Comment: So slightly above threshold we get multiple sharp peaks, slightly below threshold we get a broad gaussian-like curve and way above threshold - the gain becomes saturated, so what would the curve look like?

Comment: That's not how it works. I would suggest you start with a simple three level system and read up on its theoretical description.